# Uglifyjs - Unexpected token: name

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, angular-cli, uglifyjs

Working with **Angular-cli**, I am using a package called:

> [TPlink-Cloud-Api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tplink-cloud-api)

When I build in dev mode `ng serve`, I receive no errors and the application works. However, when I deploy to Heroku or run `ng build --prod` I get the following error:

## Error

```
ERROR in vendor.e51673ef8f2bd683eebc.bundle.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: name (LB100) [vendor.e51673ef8f2bd683eebc.bundle.js:16119,6]
```

LB100 appears to be a javascript file that is required in the main.js file of this package. If I comment it out as I am not using it in my application, another one ends up showing up in the error.

Here is a sample of the LB100.js file, perhaps someone can see some syntax that doesn't work in the current 'ugilifyjs'. If you do see the issue, how do I resolve this?

The following LB100.js is loaded in Tplink.js via a require statement:

```
var LB100 = require("./lb100.js")
```

## LB100.js

```
var TPLinkDevice = require('./device.js');

// Should work for LB100, LB110 & LB120
class LB100 extends TPLinkDevice {
  constructor(tpLink, deviceInfo){
    super(tpLink, deviceInfo);
  }

  async transition_light_state(on_off, brightness){
    // on_off: 1 for On, 0 for Off
    // brightness: 0-100
    return await super.tplink_request( {
      "smartlife.iot.smartbulb.lightingservice": {
        "transition_light_state": { "on_off": on_off, "brightness": brightness } }
      }
    )
  }

}

module.exports = LB100;
```

After some research, it appears to be an error with some syntax whereas the package doesn't compile well with ES5. I change the target in my 'TSConfig' to ES6 but it still didn't work but got an additional error related to the AppModule.

## TSConfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom",
      "es6",
      "es2015"
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see I also put in Libs as this helped others. However, I have made no progress thus far. I am using the latest version of Node.

## Package.json

```
{
  "name": "temp-sensor",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ng build --aot -prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/cli": "1.3.2",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.101",
    "angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.3",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "4.6.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "popper": "^1.0.1",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "tplink-cloud-api": "^0.2.0",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "uglify": "^0.1.5",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "9.5.0",
    "npm": "5.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {

  }
}
```

I load this package in a service:

## Loading the package:

```
declare var require: any;
const TPLink = require('../../../node_modules/tplink-cloud-api');
```

I have also run NPM Update...

I am completely lost at this point. Any help is appreciated

Comment: are you using `uglify-js` or `uglify-es`? `uglify-js` doesn't support `es6` code.

Comment: Great Question, I just used Angular-Cli, I have no idea it even used Uglifyjs until now. I did an NPM install of Uglify but have no idea how to tell webpack to use it. I'll look into this and try targeting es6 with uglify-es and get back to you.

Comment: Apparently, in Angular-cli you cannot easily configure webpack without ejecting it. Not a route I want to go in without knowing 100% this would resolve the issue as it will be a steep learning curve with limited resources.

Comment: Would love to know how to resolve this but in for use case, I don't need production. so I removed the --prod flag from my build and I'm good to go. feels messy but no other choice.

Comment: Just a general note: I would recommend to install all the typings and test frameworks with the `--save-dev` flag to install them under `devDependencies` instead of the `dependencies`.